# Dynamically running a Docker container to carry out a task as an API service in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, server, architecture, devops

I've got a basic architecture set up in Kubernetes, a Laravel container for my application level code, and a Mysql container for my database. And I'm looking to implement a code compiling API service (as a seperate container) which accepts user generated code which I then run a docker container to compile the code and return the output to the user.

There's some pretty raw implementations online but most of them use docker as a method of running user generated code compiling in an isolated environment (as you should) but the application itself is not hosted using containers or a container management system.

Questions is, how can I spin up docker containers to handle a task and then return the output to my Laravel API container before shutting the container down?

Apparently, running a docker container inside a docker container is not best practice.

The process:

1. User sends a post request to Laravel API container
2. Laravel API container will take the request and run a docker container to compile code
3. Temporary docker container will return compiled output to Laravel API container before 
   shutting down.
4. Laravel API container will return compiled response to end user.

I'm running my app in a Kubernetes cluster, and a Docker/Kubernetes solution is needed. I rather not have to run raw commands of starting a Docker container in my application level code but have a more higher level solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Kubernetes job resource to perform this kind of task.

The Jobs objects can be spawned to run a process inside and can be set to be automatically terminated afterwards. A job in Kubernetes is a supervisor for pods carrying out batch processes, that is, a process that runs for a certain time to completion. You are able to run multiple pod instances inside one job (parallel or sequentially).

Check this [page](http://kubernetesbyexample.com/jobs/) for more details about the jobs.

So basically your flow should look like this:

1. User sends request for Laravel API container
2. Laravel API container needs to interact with the API server in order to create the job.
3. Pod inside the job will compile code and after compilation, will send a request to the Laravel API pod to deliver the compiled binary.

The delivery of the binary should be coded by the user

4. Laravel API container will return compiled response to user.

[This documentation link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster) shows how to connect to the API, especially the section [Accessing the API from a Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod)

Comment: How can I get the actual response though after my container competes compilation? I can't find an option where the pod will return the output given from a container.

Comment: Since I'd be programatically running a job, I need the instance of just that job and its data.

Comment: Can you please share what kind of data are you expecting to fetch from the finished job? It`s hard to determine if there`s a feature for your type of data in k8s.

Comment: The stdout returned from executing the starting command in the container.

Comment: Once your job reach `completed` status you can fetch the logs from the pod that was created  by the job